# Flatness and tensor product of rings

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two subrings of a ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative) which commute in $R$ so that we have a ring homomorphism $R_1\otimes_\mathbb{Z} R_2\rightarrow R$ and $R$ is a module over $R_1\otimes_\mathbb{Z}R_2$. Assume also that $R$ is flat both as $R_1$- and $R_2$-module. Is then $R$ flat over $R_1\otimes_\mathbb{Z}R_2$? Is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: Counterexample: $R_1=R_2=R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Please consider expanding your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Do you mean flat as an $R_1$-$R_2$ bimodule? Or flat over both rings individually?